# What is the lexical environment of a function defined inside an object?

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
let user = {
    firstName: "John",
    sayHi() {
      console.log(`Hello, ${firstName}!`);
    }
  };
user.sayHi();
```

As far as I understand, the lexical environment is the record of the variables in the environment within and outside the function where it was defined, so why does this print undefined despite `firstName` being defined in the **parent** lexical environment of `sayHi()` i.e `user`?

Comment: "firstName" isn't a variable--it's an object property key.

Answer (score 0):

A lexical environment is created globally, by each function, and by each block.

Your code example has two lexical environments:

1. The global environment
2. The `sayHi` function body

Object literals are **not** blocks. The `{` and `}` characters have different meanings in JS depending on the context they are used in.

---

Variables belong to lexical environments. You only have one variable: `user`.

---

`firstName` is not a variable, it is a property of the object assigned to `user`. Since it is not a variable, it doesn't belong to a lexical environment.

You can only (assuming you don't use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)) access a property of an object by getting a reference to that object and reading the property from it:

e.g. You can access `user` from the parent lexical environment

```
 console.log(`Hello, ${user.firstName}!`);
```

or you can access `this` from the function's own lexical environment

```
 console.log(`Hello, ${this.firstName}!`);
```

```js
const user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi() {
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.firstName}!`);
    console.log(`Hello, ${user.firstName}!`);

  }
};
user.sayHi();
```